# How to dismiss AlertDialog inside a TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an ALertDialog that allows the user to enter a pin number.. The TextWatcher checks the length of the pin and then check if the pin is correct when the length of the text in the EditText matches the length of the store pin. I am trying to dismiss/cancel the dialog when the pin attempt is successful.
 I've attempted dialog.dismiss(); and dialog.cancel(); but neither work.

So to be clear I'm trying to dismiss the AlertDialog in the 'else' part of the if/else.  Thanks for looking

Code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder;

public void dialog() {

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setTitle("Title");
// I'm using fragment here so I'm using getView() to provide ViewGroup
// but you can provide here any other instance of ViewGroup from your Fragment / Activity
View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pword, (ViewGroup) getView(), false);
// Set up the input
final EditText input = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.input);
// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
builder.setView(viewInflated);


builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        stopReader();
        startReader();
    }
});

builder.show();

input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        m_Text = input.getText().toString();

        if (m_Text.length() == details.get(2).length()) {
            if (!input.getText().toString().equals(details.get(2))) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.mainActivity, "Incorrect pin entered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("eLOQ", "User pin is not correct");

                input.setText("");

            } else if (input.getText().toString().equals(details.get(2))) {
                controller.startStageTwo();
                Log.d("eLOQ", "User pin is correct");


                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }


    }
});
```

}

Comment: In your current code, I can't see anything your dialog variable is referring to. Have you defined it any where else ?

Comment: Yes it's declared at the top of the class . Like this:  AlertDialog.Builder builder;

Comment: What you are saying is builder declaration. I am asking about dialog declaration `dialog.dismiss();`. Where have you defined the dialog from the that line ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **dialog.dismiss()** at right place. You dimisss your dialog only when "User pin is correct" but when "pin attempt is successfull" , you not dismiss your dialog.
Change your code as below:

```
 @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    m_Text = input.getText().toString();

    if (m_Text.length() == details.get(2).length()) {
        if (!input.getText().toString().equals(details.get(2))) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.mainActivity, "Incorrect pin entered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("eLOQ", "User pin is not correct");

            input.setText("");

        } else if (input.getText().toString().equals(details.get(2))) {
            controller.startStageTwo();
            Log.d("eLOQ", "User pin is correct");
     }
     dialog.dismiss();     // dismiss your dialog here. Here your dialog will dismiss in both caases
    }


}
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog.hide(); or dialog.cancel();
```

Comment: I don't think AlertDialog.Builder has a method called `hide`